# Exclude web.config from TFS-GIT with Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

We're in the process of migrating from TFS to TFS-GIT.  Previously, we were setup with three different branches (dev, qa, prod) each with their own web.config.  When we make changes to the web.config, we'd manually move them up and force them not to merge.  Now that we're migrating to GIT, we've moved to using web.base.config and then using profiles and transforms configure it for the environment we want.

Overall, this works great however every time we try to commit it sees the web.config has been modified and we either need to manually undo it or we need to deal with potential merge conflicts.  I've tried deleting it from GIT, adding it to the git ignore, and removing it from source control but then visual studio complains that debugging isn't enabled, re-adds the web.config to the project and re-adds it to GIT.

I feel like there's a better way.  Has anyone run across a similar isuse and figured out a work around?

Comment: i am a bit unclear about your question...why is `git ignore` not working in this case?...like you would not checking in the web.config and for whoever clones this repo, VS would automatically generate it...

Comment: Visual Studio re-adds the file overriding the .gitignore.

In this specific case, if a person tries to debug they get an error that debugging isn't enabled since the web.config isn't included in the solution though it is there.  If they started with debugging, it adds it to the project file and by extension forces it to be added into the git.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found a work around that fits our needs.

First, we moved our appSettings and connectionStrings config pieces out of web.config and into files called web.appSettings.config and web.connections.config.  Neither of these files are included in the project file, and neither of these are added to source control.

```
<appSettings file="web.AppSettings.Config" />
<connectionStrings configSource="web.Connections.Config" />
```

Next, we created web.AppSettings.base.config and web.Connections.base.config that define our baseline config options.  We also created one file per build profile (debug, qa, release).  All of these files are included in source control and in the project file.

Finally, we add a pre-build event to transform web.AppSettings.base.config using web.AppSettings.[build profile].config to create web.AppSettings.config.  We do the same thing for web.Connections.config.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.AppSettings.Base.config" Transform="Web.AppSettings.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.AppSettings.config" />
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Connections.Base.config" Transform="Web.Connections.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.Connections.config" />
</Target>
```

This achieves all of our goals.  We are able to quickly change which environment we're pointing at and we're able to avoid needing to constantly commit and merge the ever changing config files.  In addition, to keep it manageable, we marked the various config files dependent to each other to make them show up as a [hierarchy in solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIGQ1.jpg) with just a simple fix in the project file.

```
<Content Include="Web.config" />
<None Include="web.AppSettings.base.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="web.AppSettings.dev.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.AppSettings.base.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="web.AppSettings.qa.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.AppSettings.base.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="web.AppSettings.release.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.AppSettings.base.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="web.Connections.base.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="web.Connections.dev.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.Connections.base.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="web.Connections.qa.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.Connections.base.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="web.Connections.release.config">
  <DependentUpon>web.Connections.base.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```